# Passing the return value of a useAppSelector to a variable in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I might have missed something super obvious when refactoring my implementation of Redux in a React application, but when I'm trying to access the value of one of my slices I get thrown some errors by the Typescript Compiler about not being able to assign a `(func) => string` to a parameter of type string.

For context, here's my implementation:

Slice:

```js
export const environmentSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'environment',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateEnvironment: (state, action:PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.value = action.payload
        }
    }
});

export const { updateEnvironment } = environmentSlice.actions;

export const selectEnvironment = (state: RootState) => state.environment.value;
```

How i've defined the interface for my environment:

```js
// Defining type for state
interface EnvironmentState {
    value: string,
};

// define the initial state using that type
const initialState: EnvironmentState = {
    value: 'live',
}
```

How `RootState` is defined in my store:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        loggedIn: loggedInReducer,
        environment: environmentReducer,
        token: tokenReducer,
},
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

How I'm trying to get the value into one of my React Components:

```js
let environment = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => {
        return state.environment.value
    });
```

I've also tried following the implementation in the redux docs here but had no luck with that: https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#use-typed-hooks-in-components

---

When assigning this value, i'm using useAppDispatch() assigned to a variable inside of the response section of a fetch request:

```js
fetch('/api/authenticate', requestOptions)
            .then(async response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    let data = await response.json();
                    dispatch({ type: toggle });
                    dispatch({ type: updateToken, payload: data.token });

                    webHelpers.get('/api/user', 'default', 'auth', data.token, (data: any) => {
                        dispatch({ type: updateUser, payload: data.full_name })
                    });

                    // 
                    navigate('../management/staff');
```

Please note: The environment isn't updated upon sign-in but only once the user selects an option from a drop-down menu in the DOM. It's directly after this sign-in and navigation that the application crashes, however, as it states it cannot read the 'value' on the following:

```js
const token = useAppSelector(state => {
    return state.token.value
});
```

The above is reached *after* the `navigate('../management/staff');` is called.

---

Edit: Accidently included wrong code snippet when showing useAppSelector in use. Update to fix.

Edit2: Added in section about the dispatches that assigns these values.

Edit3: Managed to resolve the solution but not in the exact way I'd hoped so I'll leave this open. The issue appeared to be that the attempts to dispatch data via the slices I'd added to my store's reducer didn't work, having all of those methods on one sole slice resolved the issue. This isn't ideal as I'd wanted 3 separate slices to manage each of these states separately. There must be some issue in my redux store with setting these up to work independently.

Comment: Where are you using `useAppSelector`?

Comment: Btw if you're using this as a constant for `development`, `production`, etc. this does not really belong in redux. Unless your environment can dynamically change at runtime. Usually the environment is already defined at build time and won't change anymore (not global state, just an app-wide constant value).

Comment: @timotgl apologies, I'd posted the wrong code snipped for the environment variable being set. Environment in this context is a setting being used as part of an API call to fetch from different database environments. Updating post to include corrected code snippet

Comment: My guess is that `action.payload` is not what you think it is. Couldn't really spot anything wrong in your snippets otherwise. Maybe you can share the code that dispatches it? You don't need to annotate the state argument in `useAppSelector` btw, it already knows the shape of the state.

Comment: @timotgl I have a feeling there's some logic error somewhere along the dispatch chain as the value for environment isn't being set when the application runs through the sign in process which sends off the dispatch calls for assigning basic information like username, token, environment etc. I'll read through and see what I find before updating.

Comment: @timotgl added further detail about where crashing occurs

Comment: I can only speculate at this point. Any chance `navigate` should wait for the `updateUser` to have finished? Have you debugged what `state.token` looks like in the problematic `useAppSelector`?

Comment: @timotgl i've *somewhat* resolved the issue, turns out the problem was with my redux store not really working with the second 2 slices i'd extracted this functionality out into. The useAppSelector was functioning just fine, the store just isn't configured properly in some way I don't fully understand.